# Can't find the right regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I spent the last 4 hours trying to find out how to write some regex expressions but every time when I think I get it, my test fails... 
Can anybody help me or give me some clues to get me on the right track? I have a cheatsheet in front of me.

I want the following: a regex that give's me every word out a string that has a `?` to it.

Example: `this is a? example sentence? to test the regex?`
I want `a`, `sentence` and `regex` as results.

The best regex I've come up with is `/\w\?/`.

Comment: what is the best one you have come up with?

Comment: The best was / /w\?/ but this ony gives one character with the ? not the whole word..

Answer (score 4):

A naive regex that only considers words that are entirely made up of ASCII letters could be

```
\b[A-Za-z]+(?=\?)
```

The `\b` [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) makes sure that the entire word is matched, and the `(?=\?)` [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) asserts that there is a question mark following immediately afterwards, without making that question mark part of the match.

Comment: The second `\b` is redundant :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that first, you can define a word as `\S+` (you didn't define a word, so I'll just go with that. Change to something else, for instance a more restrictive character class if you want to, maybe like `\w+`), or maybe even `\b\S+\b`.

From this, you need to put a check for `?`, which can be done by means of a positive lookahead `(?= ... )`.

Now, you could start with `(?=\?)` but that would check one position at a time in the regex, and won't be practical if ever the `?` is at the beginning of a word. So, you also need to allow any number of characters (even 0) before finding the `?`: `(?=.*\?)`.

Now, `.*` will allow the regex go across words, which is not ideal, replace it with `\S*`:

```
\b(?=\S*\?)\S+
```

And you can actually drop the last `\b` since a word won't go further than `\S`.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pL6oN1)

Comment: no match groups though - regex is good for matching and will be consistent - brackets need adjusting (but can't see where) to allow for matches

Comment: @GrahamRitchie If the `?` can be anywhere in the word, you'll need at least two capture groups and also modify the regex. In that case, I think a replace on the results would be more appropriate to remove the `?`.

Comment: valid point - i read the question (as per my regex) to simply be ? at the end of the sentence - you are right - I am normally the first to tell people to stop using regex as the solution to everything - and now I am doing it - urgh!

Answer (score 1):

Regex is as follows

```
 $string = "this is a? example sentence? to test the regex?"; 

 $output_array = array();
 preg_match_all("/\b([a-zA-Z]*)\?/", $string, $output_array);

 print_r($output_array[1]);
```

This will return all the matches without the `?` at the end.